# Ajax Autocomplete in IIS

Tags: ajax, autocompletebox

I am using ajax autocomplete extender for autocomplete functionality. This is working fine when i am running from Visual Studio.
My Code Below:

Service Method:

[OperationContract]
    public List autoCompleteStreetName(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        string query = "SELECT TOP 20 streetName1 FROM TBL_Property_Information WHERE streetName1 LIKE '%" + prefixText + "%'";
        DataAccessLayer dAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
        List industryNames = new List();
        DataTable objIndustryTable = new DataTable();
        objIndustryTable = dAccess.FillDataTable(query);
        for (int i = 0; i < objIndustryTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            industryNames.Add(objIndustryTable.Rows[i]["streetName1"].ToString());
        }
        return industryNames;
    }

Issue is
When hosted into an IIS server the AutoComplete is not working. The Result list is showing only the html,head,link tags in vertical

I am using Form Authentication

The Result Values are like Below

h
t
m
l
h
e
a
d
l
i
n
k

r
e
l

.
.
.
.
h
t
m
l
/

> 

This is always coming only when hosted in IIS server.
What might be the problem?
Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Arup. Can you please give an example of both the working and not working results? Perhaps in the form of returned HTML?

Comment: Thank you Rhughes.. <br/> from visual studio this is coming , When i entered Ar, Result is : Arup,Arun, Aruna,Arupa but when hosted in IIS this is just like a vertical texts having values, <,h, t, m, l, >, h, e, a, d, l, i, n, k....

Comment: When the website is hosted in IIS, is the datasouce the same?

Comment: Datasource is the Remote One. when i am using J Query. this is working. Problem is, The Web service is not called when hosted in IIS server

Comment: It sounds like an error is being returned. Can you please update your question with the full HTML being returned?

Comment: Hi @Arup, we really need some code to help.  If you remove the `autpcomplete` attribute, does it still happen?

Comment: hi BanksySan, Please see my edited question. When hosted in IIS, Ajax could not call the Webservice. i am using Form Authentication